# What is internal implementation of Iteration in java that allows remove() method to work?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator

Any items of a list when iterated by foreach loop cannot be removed. However, when we iterate it through iterator, it can be removed by remove() method of iterator.

I understand the concept of fail-fast and fail-safe, and also aware that Iterator is the way java provides us an option to remove. But I wanted to know the internal implementation of Iterator's remove() method provided by java, which facilitates this operation to be done.

```
import java.util.*;
public class RemoveCollection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
    ls.add("apple");
    ls.add("orange");
    ls.add("kiwi");

    Iterator it = ls.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        //works fine and the item is removed from list
        it.remove();
    }

    ls.add("apple");
    ls.add("orange");
    ls.add("kiwi");
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.next();
        //throws concurrentmodification exception
        ls.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: normally when installing the JDK you have the option to install the source code of the Java classes: `src.zip` in the `lib` folder of the JDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can know that by simply looking at the source code of ArrayList, which comes with the JDK:

ArrayList has this field (inherited from AbstractList):

```
protected transient int modCount = 0;
```

It's incremented each time an operation is done on the list. For example, `ArrayList.remove()` has the following instruction:

```
modCount++;
```

The iterator of the ArrayList has the following code:

```
int expectedModCount = modCount;

public E next() {
   checkForComodification();
   [...]
}

final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

So, as you can see, when it iterates, it checks that the modCount of the list hasn't been modified.

And its `remove()` method does the following:

```
ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
[...];
expectedModCount = modCount;
```

So it removes the element from the list, and then updates its `expectedModCount`, so that the next operation done with the iterator doesn't fail when calling `checkForComodification()`.

The key thing to understand is that the method `iterator()` returns an object that has access to the internal structure of the list. Not only to be able to iterate over its elements, but also to check if that list has been modified between two operations done using the iterator.

Comment: Sorry, but I wanted to know about the remove() method of Iterator, not ArrayList. I mean, we get an Iterator reference by say Iterator itr = ls.iterator() and then use itr.remove(). So this basically is the method of ArrayList which gets called? I wasn't aware. Let me have a look. Thank you

Comment: And my answer explains that. But you need to read it completely: *The iterator of the ArrayList has the following code: [...] And its remove() method does the following: [...]*

Comment: Also wanted to know why is iterator fail-fast as per official document of oracle java.  It is safely removing the items of the list without throwing ConcurrentModificationException, still it is fail fast

Comment: It fails fast because as soon as you call next(), it detects if the list has been modified while iterating. that's what the checkForComodification  method does.

Answer (score 0):

The [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) extends [`AbstractList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html). This abstract class contains method `iterator()` which returns a new Iterator (line 287). You can see the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractList.java):

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Few lines below (on the line 330) there is a definition of the `private class Itr implements Iterator<E>` which defines and implements the method `remove()` on the line 368:

```
public void remove() {
    if (lastRet < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    checkForComodification();

    try {
        AbstractList.this.remove(lastRet);
        if (lastRet < cursor)
            cursor--;
        lastRet = -1;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will get back, going to have a look